# Create Consecutive Periods in R That Are Continuous

Tags: r, dplyr

Given this dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- tribble(
  ~person, ~start, ~end,
  '1', '2000-01-01', '2000-12-31',
  '1', '2001-01-01', '2002-07-31',
  '1', '2001-04-01', '2001-06-30',
  '1', '2001-08-01', '2001-12-31',
  '1', '2002-01-01', '2002-12-31',
  '2', '2000-01-01', '2000-11-30',
  '2', '2001-01-01', '2001-12-31') |> 
  mutate(start = lubridate::as_date(start),
         end   = lubridate::as_date(end))
```

I am trying to produce output to show:

```
person     start         end
1          2000-01-01    2002-12-31
2          2000-01-01    2001-11-30
2          2001-01-01    2001-12-31
```

These data have overlapping dates so I am trying to create a group of the start and end date that are consecutive without a lapse.

I tried this

```
df |> 
  distinct() |>
  arrange(person, start, end) |> 
  mutate(
    gap = start - lag(end, default = min(start))
  ) |>
  group_by(person) |> 
  summarise(
    MIN_START = min(start),
    MAX_END   = max(end)
  )
```

but this takes the first min and last max dates, and ignores any breaks in-between.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more frugal function, this one uses a fraction of the memory that the first function did (below, kept for comparison).

```r
fun <- function(starts, ends) {
  S <- starts; E <- ends
  for (i in rev(seq_along(S))) {
    ind <- ind <- which(S[-i] <= S[i] & S[i] <= E[-i] + 1)
    if (length(ind)) {
      ind <- max(ind) + (max(ind) > i)
      S[ind] <- min(S[c(ind, i)])
      E[ind] <- max(E[c(ind, i)])
      S <- S[-i]
      E <- E[-i]
    }
  }
  data.frame(start=S, end=E)
}

reframe(df, .by=person, fun(start, end))
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#   person start      end       
#   <chr>  <date>     <date>    
# 1 1      2000-01-01 2002-12-31
# 2 2      2000-01-01 2000-11-30
# 3 2      2001-01-01 2001-12-31
```

---

*(Old answer, not needed.)*

Using a helper function (which is admittedly brute-force):

```r
fun <- function(starts, ends) {
  x <- unique(sort(do.call(c, Map(seq, starts, ends, list(by="day")))))
  x <- split(x, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x) > 1))) |>
    lapply(function(z) setNames(data.frame(as.list(range(z))),
                                c("start", "end")))
  do.call(rbind, x)
}
```

We then can do

```r
dplyr::reframe(df, .by=person, fun(start, end))
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#   person start      end       
#   <chr>  <date>     <date>    
# 1 1      2000-01-01 2002-12-31
# 2 2      2000-01-01 2000-11-30
# 3 2      2001-01-01 2001-12-31
```

Comment: This function is extremely fast on my very large dataset.  Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Update `end` with the latest end date and then find the consecutive time intervals.

```
df %>%
  mutate(end=accumulate2(end,lead(start)[-n()],function(x,y,z) as_date(ifelse((x-z)>1,max(x,y),y))),
         grp=c(TRUE,(start-lag(end)>1)[-1]),
         grp=cumsum(grp),
         .by=person) %>%
  reframe(start=min(start),
          end=max(end),
          .by=c(grp,person))

# A tibble: 3 × 4
    grp person start      end       
  <int> <chr>  <date>     <date>    
1     1 1      2000-01-01 2002-12-31
2     1 2      2000-01-01 2000-11-30
3     2 2      2001-01-01 2001-12-31
```

Comment: (Sorry, I hit the wrong "edit" button :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Edit: I've just seen you already have an answer(s) with the same logic so ignore (though the (base) `cummax` function might be worth using)]

[Edit2: Actually I will propose this a solution as it turns out to be a lot faster as well as (to me at least) simpler. dplyr version added.]

Grouping by `person`:

1. get latest end date so far (using `cummax`)
2. ID each spell (`cumsum` of flag for start >1 day later than latest end date)
3. aggregate to spells

`dplyr`:

```
df |>
    mutate(cummax_end = as.Date(cummax(as.integer(end))), .by=person) |>
    mutate(spell = cumsum(c(TRUE, (start - lag(cummax_end) > 1)[-1])), .by=person) |>
    summarise(start = first(start), end = last(cummax_end), .by=c(person, spell))
```

`data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setorder(setDT(df),person, start, end)

df[, cummax_end := as.Date(cummax(as.integer(end))), by=person
 ][, spell := cumsum(.I == .I[1] | (start - shift(cummax_end)) > 1), by=person
 ][, .(start = first(start), end = last(cummax_end)), by=.(person, spell)]
```

A slightly altered example so there are 2 spells for person 1:

```
df <- data.frame(
  person = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
  start = as.Date(c("2000-01-01", "2001-01-01", "2001-04-01", "2002-10-01", "2003-01-01", "2000-01-01", "2001-01-01")),
  end   = as.Date(c("2000-12-31", "2002-07-31", "2001-06-30", "2003-01-31", "2002-12-31", "2000-11-30", "2001-12-31"))
)

   person spell      start        end
    <num> <int>     <Date>     <Date>
1:      1     1 2000-01-01 2002-07-31
2:      1     2 2002-10-01 2003-01-31
3:      2     1 2000-01-01 2000-11-30
4:      2     2 2001-01-01 2001-12-31
```

Timings if relevant:

```
df <- rbindlist(lapply(1:1e3, \(j) df))[, person := rleid(person)]

Unit: milliseconds
           expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
    cust_func() 1483.5969 1558.2218 1611.9176 1622.7629 1661.6742 1692.7049    10
 purrr_accum2() 1539.4260 1588.3180 1606.9303 1604.1265 1629.8823 1678.7693    10
      cummax_()  457.4260  470.3525  487.5223  487.6372  497.2030  519.8956    10
    cummax_dt()  125.0371  135.1678  138.6562  140.1660  142.7908  146.6276    10
```